# R: split uneven length string with missing separator into two cols: separate characters and numbers

Tags: r, string, split

I wonder how can I split the column, containing characters and numbers into two columns: character & number. The thing is that I do not have any special character in between that I can simple use `gsub(old, new, names)`, also the number of my characters preceding 'number' differs:

Example:

```
# Create data frame with values containing characters and strings: both of uneven sizes:
df<- data.frame(names = c("ALL10", 
                          "ALL3", 
                          "CCF8", 
                          "not_CCF19"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What I want to get: column `names` split in `chars` and `nums`:

```
      names  chars   nums
1     ALL10     ALL    10
2      ALL3     ALL     3
3      CCF8     CCF     8
4 not_CCF19 not_CCF    19
```

I was thinking that I can try to:

- replace `not_CCF` into something with exactly 3 characters,
- then split the first 3 characters into one column and leftover into the second one, etc.

but I can't really figure it out, and maybe there is something easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract` from `tidyr` to get data in two columns where 1st column would have everything until a number is encountered and the second column would have the number part.

```
tidyr::extract(df, names, c('chars', 'nums'), '(.*?)(\\d+)', remove = FALSE)

#      names   chars nums
#1     ALL10     ALL   10
#2      ALL3     ALL    3
#3      CCF8     CCF    8
#4 not_CCF19 not_CCF   19
```

---

You can use the same regex in `str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(df$names, '(.*?)(\\d+)')[, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

In *base* you can use `regexpr` to find the position of the first digit and use `substr` to get the string until or after this position.

```
i <- regexpr("\\d", df$names)
df$chars <- substr(df$names, 1, i-1)
df$nums <- substring(df$names, i)
df
#      names   chars nums
#1     ALL10     ALL   10
#2      ALL3     ALL    3
#3      CCF8     CCF    8
#4 not_CCF19 not_CCF   19
```